# Changing a pixel's alpha value with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have an image with some opaque white pixels (rgba = FFFFFFFF).  I want to change those pixels to a different color with a different transparency, say rgba = 33333355.

I use

```
convert test.png -fuzz 1% -alpha set -fill '#33333355' -opaque '#ffffffff' test2.png
```

The pixel's colors are changed properly, but not the alpha values, so I get new pixels with rgba = 333333FF !

Why can I change the rgb value, but not the alpha value?? How can I change the alpha value also?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your just missing the [-channel](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#channel) option. I believe the default channel value is 'RGBK,sync'; however, your attempting to alter pixels as 'RGBA'.

```sh
convert test.png \
    -fuzz 1% \
    -alpha set \
    -channel RGBA \
    -fill '#33333355' \
    -opaque '#ffffffff' \
    test2.png
```